# How to make an object from a bloc available for all other bloc in Flutter

Tags: flutter, bloc, state-management

I am using Bloc for my Flutter project. I have created three blocs. These are AuthenticationBloc, FirebaseDatabaseBloc, and ChatMessagesBloc. When the user gets authenticated, AuthenticationBloc emits a state called authenticated with a user object.

I want to make this user object available inside FirebaseDatabaseBloc and ChatMessagesBloc. What is the clean way of doing this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is achievable by BLoC-to-BLoC communication. The simplest way is to pass your BLoC reference by the other's constructor and subscribe to BLoC changes:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final authenticationBloc = AuthenticationBloc();

  return MultiBlocProvider(
    providers: [
      BlocProvider<AuthenticationBloc>.value(value: authenticationBloc),
      BlocProvider<FirebaseDatabaseBloc>(
        create: (_) => FirebaseDatabaseBloc(
          authenticationBloc: authenticationBloc,
        ),
      ),
    ],
    child: ...,
  );
}
```

Then, inside the `FirebaseDatabaseBloc` you can subscribe to changes:

```
class FirebaseDatabaseBloc extends Bloc<FirebaseDatabaseEvent, FirebaseDatabaseBloc> {
  final AuthenticationBloc authenticationBloc;

  StreamSubscription<AuthenticationState> _authenticationStateStreamSubscription;

  FirebaseDatabaseBloc({
    @required this.authenticationBloc,
  }) : super(...) {
    _authenticationStateStreamSubscription = authenticationBloc.listen(_onAuthenticationBlocStateChange);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> close() async {
    _authenticationStateStreamSubscription.cancel();

    return super.close();
  }

  void _onAuthenticationBlocStateChange(AuthenticationState authState) {
    // Do whatever you want with the auth state
  }
}
```

For more info, you can check this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ricBLKHeubM

Answer (score 1):

Well, This is year 2022 and a lot has changed. Bloc to Bloc to communication via the constructor is now considered a bad practice. Nobody said it won't work though but trust me, you'd end up tightly coupling your code.

> Generally, sibling dependencies between two entities in the same architectural layer should be avoided at all costs, as it creates tight-coupling which is hard to maintain. Since blocs reside in the business logic architectural layer, no bloc should know about any other bloc.
> [documentation](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/architecture?id=bloc-to-bloc-communication).

You should rather try this:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocListener<WeatherCubit, WeatherState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        // When the first bloc's state changes, this will be called.
        //
        // Now we can add an event to the second bloc without it having
        // to know about the first bloc.
        BlocProvider.of<SecondBloc>(context).add(SecondBlocEvent());
      },
      child: TextButton(
        child: const Text('Hello'),
        onPressed: () {
          BlocProvider.of<FirstBloc>(context).add(FirstBlocEvent());
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I hope it helps!